# Creating and looping through date array in GBQ

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I need to create end-of-month dates as an array and them loop through them to calculate each skuid quantity at the end of the month (also need to union each eom information in one table, but it will be another issue), starting from 2021-01-31.
Tried this query (create array of eom --> then unnest them in the for loop  --> use each date to filter the existing dataset), but it does not work, where could be problem?

```
DECLARE eom_ranges ARRAY<DATE>;
SET eom_ranges =   (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(LAST_DAY(dt, MONTH)) AS eoms 
                    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-01-01',CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS dt);

FOR field IN
  (SELECT * from UNNEST(eom_ranges) AS `date`)
DO
    SELECT
        field AS extraction_date
        , wrh.sku_id
        , SUM(wrh.amount) AS invoiced_quantity
    FROM `xxx.xxx.warehouse` as wrh
    WHERE wrh.modified_date <= field
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING invoiced_quantity <> 0;
END FOR;
```

Comment: When I have try running this code, using made up data, I'm getting error with having clause. Its the same error you are getting? Some sample data will be good for the case. Also, It must be an array? I think, it can be done with selects.

Comment: my bad, changed having clause.
I suppose it should be array, as I can initialize array with eom date ranges and then iterate through this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below should fit your calculation.

```
with valid_days as (
SELECT dt as first_day_val,
LAST_DAY(dt, MONTH) as last_day_val
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY( '2021-01-01',CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as dt
)
select 
  last_day_val,
  sku_id, 
  sum(amount) as invoiced_quantity
from `my-project-id.my-dataset.my-table` wrh
inner join valid_days vd on modified_date >= vd.first_day_val and modified_date <= vd.last_day_val
where amount <> 0
GROUP BY 1,2
order by 1
```

Here you can find more information about [with](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause) clause.